How to install UWP app on a machine that does not have AppInstaller app
I need to install my side-loaded UWP on a target machine that does not have AppInstaller app.
Therefore, obviously, trying to double-click on the .msixbundle is not producing anything.
The target machine does not even have the cmdlet Add-AppPackage in powershell.
And I have been only able to find the AppInstaller "offline" download package as a .msixbundle!
Is there a downloadable link of AppInstaller that is a .exe or a .msi that I can install in the old fashion way of the Win32 apps?
Or do you have any additional options?
Thank you very much!

One can "deploy" to a remote device from VS, so if you can connect to the target machine (say via wifi) you can try that.

This procedure is meant to be applied on machines owned by customers, which I do not have access to. We need to provide the side-loaded installation package to the IT folks of the customers who in turn will install such packages.

Why can't you distribute your app via The Store? The Store has a "corporate channel" you can use to distribute your app only to your customers.

@GerrySchmitz because the customer has an internal policy such that they do not want the Microsoft Store to be available. BTW, please also note that this is the case for a large number of enterprise customers. Not only they remove the Microsoft Store app from their Windows clients, but also the AppxInstaller app. And sometimes they also remove the cmdlet Add-AppPackage...

Anybody else have any idea on this topic? Thank you!

You could write a small wrapper application that uses the PackageManager UWP API to install the .msixbundle file.

Hi @zett42, thanks for the proposal! I am a little bit confused, though, because it seems to me that the API you refer to is a UWP API, which means that I have to create a UWP App to install another UWP App? If that's the case, how can I install the first UWP app in the first place?

@CristianoGhersi There is a range of UWP API that can be called without a package identity from desktop apps (using WinRT). I'm not sure if the PackageManager API falls into this range, but it could be worth a try.

Upon further research, the PackageManager API is listed as requiring a package identity. There is still hope though: "starting in Windows 10, version 2004, you can grant package identity to an app simply by building and registering a package with external location with your app." See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/grant-identity-to-nonpackaged-apps
